# xaml - anchor the left of a textblock to the right of the container

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml, textblock

if i have a textblock which i want to vary in width by the size of its contents, but i want the left of the textblock to maintain a certain spacing from the right of the container... how is this accomplished? I feel I'm overlooking something simple. Im specifically using WPF, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be to place the TextBlock inside a `StackPanel` like this:-

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlighment="Right" Width="200">
   <TextBlock Text="Some Text or binding" />
</StackPanel>
```

Where Width 200 represents the fixed distance you want the left border of the `TextBlock` to be away from the right border of the element containing the `StackPanel`.

Comment: yes this will do it. Guess I was curious if a direct property can be set on the textblock to accomplish this, but i think this is going to be the only way. thx

Comment: @boomhauer:  I guess what you were looking for is similar to WinForms Anchor feature.  WPF and Silverlight don't have that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `HorizontalAlignment` property.

```
HorizontalAlignment="Right"

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Yellow">
    <StackPanel
        Background="AliceBlue"
        Margin="50">
        <TextBlock
            Text="Some text"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <TextBlock
            Text="Some other longer text"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Produces this output:

[image]

Comment: the problem is: the right side of the textblock will be changing, due to changing lengths of text. so the left side of the box will be jumping around. so, i want the left side to be anchored to the RIGHT of the container. follow?

Comment: I think so.  Try the HorizontalAligment property.

Comment: im looking to have the left edge of the text stay put, thus actually left aligned. but, left aligned a set distance from the right side of the container!

Comment: Yep then as Anthony displayed, you'll have to put another container around the TextBlock to accomplish what you want.